# Removing undefined from an Array that contains square brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Below you can see the Array that I"m dealing with. Ultimately I want to remove the duplicate square brackets, but for now I'm just trying to remove that `undefined` on row2 of the array. I've tried many methods and just can't seem to filter that out, could it be due to the additional square brackets? Any insight would be great!

*Server Side Array*

```
[
  [ '["windows","osx","linux"]' ],
  [ undefined ],
  [ '["windows","osx"]' ],
  [ '["windows"]' ],
  [ '["windows","osx","android"]' ],
  [ '["windows","linux"]' ],
  [ '["windows","osx","linux","android"]' ],
  [ '["web"]' ],
  [ '["windows","linux","android"]' ],
  [ '["windows","android"]' ],
  [ '["android"]' ],
  [ '["osx"]' ]
]
```

**Code**

```
    // filter out duplicates
    function arrUnique(arr) {
        var cleaned = [];
        platform.forEach(function(itm) {
            var unique = true;
            cleaned.forEach(function(itm2) {
                if (_.isEqual(itm, itm2)) unique = false;
            });
            if (unique)  cleaned.push(itm);
        });
        return cleaned;
    }
    
    var duplicateRemoval = arrUnique(platform);
    var filteredOut = duplicateRemoval.filter(e => e != null);
    console.log(filteredOut);
```

Comment: Where is the array coming from? You’d better fix it from it’s source

Comment: I'd love too! @LelioFaieta but unfortunately its coming from a json i'm pulling from https://itch.io/bundle/520/games.json  I can't control it.

Comment: What happens if you try to use json.parse on it once?

Comment: That's just another array. `if ( <length of the array === 1> && <the only element is undefined> ) then remove that element` (presumable with `.filter()` or `.reduce()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for removing `undefined` item you can use one of these codes
if

1. you don't want to change the main `data` ,`find` method can be used.

.

```
var data = [
  [ '["windows","osx","linux"]' ],
  [ undefined ],
  [ '["windows","osx"]' ],
  [ '["windows"]' ],
  [ '["windows","osx","android"]' ],
  [ '["windows","linux"]' ],
  [ '["windows","osx","linux","android"]' ],
  [ '["web"]' ],
  [ '["windows","linux","android"]' ],
  [ '["windows","android"]' ],
  [ '["android"]' ],
  [ '["osx"]' ]
]

var res = data.filter( item => Array.isArray(item) && item.length > 0 && item[0] !== undefined)
```

this code changes the `data` and removed `undefined` items

```
var i = 0
while( i< data.length){
  if(Array.isArray(data[i]) && data[i].length > 0 && data[i][0] !== undefined) {
    i++;
  } else {
    data.splice(i , 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I didn't know about this. That was super helpful!

Comment: `Array.isArray()` is unnecessary because all elements of `data` are arrays. And that's a really complicated way of doing it (see sivakos answer)

Comment: it will be helpful to protect the method from unexpected data. if you are sure about data you can remove it

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `undefined`, You can just use the filter.
(If the array has more element of undefined, then change filter accordingly with either some or every method).

```js
const data = [
  ['["windows","osx","linux"]'],
  [undefined],
  ['["windows","osx"]'],
  ['["windows"]'],
  ['["windows","osx","android"]'],
  ['["windows","linux"]'],
  ['["windows","osx","linux","android"]'],
  ['["web"]'],
  ['["windows","linux","android"]'],
  ['["windows","android"]'],
  ['["android"]'],
  ['["osx"]'],
];

const res = data.filter(([item]) => item);

console.log(res);
```